# Enabling CORS in Web API Core and Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an WEB API Core hosted in a different local host and I am trying to access it from my MVC Core app through AngularJS $http service.

Here is my homeController.js

```
app.controller("homeController", function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.accessToken = "";
var serviceBase = "https://localhost:44351/";
var request = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: serviceBase + "api/token",
    data:
        {
            username: "DemoUser",
            password: "Password"
        },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST'
    }
});
request.success(function (result) {
    $scope.accessToken = result;
});
});
```

To enable cross origin calls in the Startup.cs of the WEB API Core

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        ...
        services.AddCors();
        ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
       ..
        app.UseCors(builder =>
        builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44352/")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        );
      ..
 }
```

Despite of this I am still getting this error in chrome.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:44351/api/token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:44352' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I am able to call api from Postman client.
Any steps I missed in this? Please help.

**Fixes I did for this**:

In the WebAPI project **web.config** file

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://localhost:xxxxx" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
...
```

In **StartUp.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddCors();
//  services.AddMvc();
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{  app.UseCors(builder =>
        builder
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials()
        );}
```

Chrome didn't allowed me to use * in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` field.

Also added `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.0.0"` in project.json

Thanks everyone for help. I am really noob at this.

Comment: copy and show headers from request and response

Comment: I was able to overcome the issue, see edits for details.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to enable CORS on web api core side then follow these steps-

First, add dependency in project.json - `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.0.0",`

then enable CORS in `startup.cs` like this-

```
app.UseCors(builder => {
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
});
```

In case if you want to restrict to specific origin then you can do like this-

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("example.com"));
```

You can find more information about CORS [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html)

See if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In your Configure method, you forgot to allow any methods, so the POST request failed. Your Configure method should look like this :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
       ..
        app.UseCors(builder =>
        builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44352/")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials()
        );
      ..
 }
```

And you forgot to send credentials, if you don't and if you use anthentication cookies or anti XHRF they are not going to be sent  :

```
var request = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: serviceBase + "api/token",
    data:
        {
            username: "DemoUser",
            password: "Password"
        },
    withCredentials: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put these:

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST'
}
```

In server response, not client request